# Get element on a new window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an element in a new opened window (or tab, in my case) but I can't do it.

My idea is to open a site an as soon as it loads, enter my username and password to login.

I tried the following code:

```
var site = open("site url");
user = site.document.getElementById("username");
user.value = "myUsername";
```

The console shows the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'value' of null.

I tried to use `setTimeout` and `.onload`, but it also didn't work

Can anyone help me?

I know this may seem simple but I have just started programming in JavaScript and I am still learning.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I want to create a bookmark that instead of just opening the website it also logs in

Comment: This all depends on what you are making, is this a google extension? Or is it your own site?

Comment: @HermanNeple It's just a bookmark; not my site

Comment: You can't open any random site and mess with their DOM. It's a security thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider two HTML files:

openwindow.htm – this has a text box and a button, clicking the button opens the target.htm file in a new browser window
target.htm – this has code to change the value of the text box present in the parent window(openwindow.htm) that opens this file

openwindow.htm:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
      function openwindow()
      {
          window.open("target.htm","_blank","height=200,width=400,
          status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no")
      }
</script>
<body>
      <form name=frm>
          <input id=text1 type=text>
          <input type=button onclick="javascript:openwindow()" value="Open window..">
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that if the parameter ”_blank” is not provided then the functionality will differ between IE and Firefox, in firefox a new tab will be opened instead of a new window. Just use window.open("target.htm") and see the difference yourself. For more info about window.open() method and its parameters, see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx. Also note, in , the id attribute is necessary, then only the code of target.htm(shown below) will execute in Firefox.

target.htm:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
     function changeparent()
     {
          window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value="Value changed.."
     }
</script>
<body>
     <form>
          <input type=button onclick="javascript:changeparent()" value="Change opener's textbox's value..">
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here I've shown you that child is accessing the parent window but you can do vice versa also..**